# Underscore: Remove object having some duplicate properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

can somebody help me remove object from array having some duplicate properties.

```
var data = [{
    "IDPOSITION": "1",
    "LATITUDE": "5.35961",
    "LONGITUDE": "-3.10095",
    "IDUSAGER": "1",
    "DATECREATION": "2013-10-12 21:53:09"
}, {
    "IDPOSITION": "2",
    "LATITUDE": "5.35961",
    "LONGITUDE": "-4.00095",
    "IDUSAGER": "1",
    "DATECREATION": "2013-10-12 21:53:51"
}, {
    "IDPOSITION": "3",
    "LATITUDE": "5.35961",
    "LONGITUDE": "-4.00095",
    "IDUSAGER": "1",
    "DATECREATION": "2013-10-12 21:53:53"
}];
```

I need to remove objects having same couple of (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE). In the example above data[1] and data[2] are duplicate from criteras (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
_.uniq(data, function(x) { return x.LATITUDE + "/" + x.LONGITUDE })
```

Basically, you provide a function that is supposed to return a hash value based on selected properties.

Comment: thx for return x.LATITUDE + "/" + x.LONGITUDE. I didn't know about "/"

Comment: @MarcelDjaman: there's nothing special about `/` here - it's just a random char I used to create a string hash.

Comment: Always thought about return property. thanks for pointing me about the hash