# Remove Duplicate objects from JSON Array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a series of lists in HTML of the form:

```
<div>
    <h3>Math K</h3>
    <li>Counting & Cardinality</li>
    <li>Geometry</li>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Math 1</h3>
    <li>Counting & Cardinality</li>
    <li>Orders of Operation</li>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Math 2</h3>
    <li>Geometry</li>
</div>
```

My original though was to create an array and push that into the `<div>` element on the page with `$("#divid").append(array)`. I created an array that looks like this:

```
var standardsList = [
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"}
];
```

And I need to remove the duplicates so that something like this remains:

```
var standardsList = [
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"}
];
```

I've tried installing underscore.js and using ._uniq but that only seems to work when a single `key:value` pair appears in the object. I can't seem to get it to work across multiple keys.

When I try something like:

```
var uniqueStandards = _.uniq(standardsList, function(item, key, Domain){
    return item.Domain;
});
```

I only get the first three unique values (one per grade). But I need all the unique values across both grade and domain. Is there a simple way to feed both keys to the _.uniq function?

Ultimately, I need a list with the each unique grade as the header and the unique domains as the list items to pass into an HTML page.

Comment: `return item.Grade + item.Domain`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Underscore: Remove object having some duplicate properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426994/underscore-remove-object-having-some-duplicate-properties)

Comment: For those looking for a json deduplicator, as I was, this provides such a great resource using a hashTable lookup and array.filter() -> https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/deduplicate-an-array/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Ultimately, I need a list with the each unique grade as the header and the unique domains as the list items to pass into an HTML page. I may be going about this wrong, so if there is an easier way to accomplish that end goal, I am open to ideas.

So you don't actually need that output array in the format you asked about.

That being the case, I would cut directly to the chase with a very simple and efficient solution:

```
var grades = {};
standardsList.forEach( function( item ) {
    var grade = grades[item.Grade] = grades[item.Grade] || {};
    grade[item.Domain] = true;
});

console.log( JSON.stringify( grades, null, 4 ) );
```

The resulting `grades` object is:

```
{
    "Math K": {
        "Counting & Cardinality": true,
        "Geometry": true
    },
    "Math 1": {
        "Counting & Cardinality": true,
        "Orders of Operation": true
    },
    "Math 2": {
        "Geometry": true
    }
}
```

One interesting thing about this approach is that it is very fast. Note that it makes only a single pass through the input array, unlike other solutions that require multiple passes (whether you write them yourself or whether `_.uniq()` does it for you). For a small number of items this won't matter, but it's good to keep in mind for larger lists.

And with this object you now have everything you need to run any code or generate any other format you want. For example, if you do need the exact array output format you mentioned, you can use:

```
var outputList = [];
for( var grade in grades ) {
    for( var domain in grades[grade] ) {
        outputList.push({ Grade: grade, Domain: domain });
    }
}

JSON.stringify( outputList, null, 4 );
```

This will log:

```
[
    {
        "Grade": "Math K",
        "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"
    },
    {
        "Grade": "Math K",
        "Domain": "Geometry"
    },
    {
        "Grade": "Math 1",
        "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"
    },
    {
        "Grade": "Math 1",
        "Domain": "Orders of Operation"
    },
    {
        "Grade": "Math 2",
        "Domain": "Geometry"
    }
]
```

[Rai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3843851/rai) asks in a comment how this line of code works:

```
var grade = grades[item.Grade] = grades[item.Grade] || {};
```

This is a common idiom for fetching an object property or providing a default value if the property is missing. Note that the `=` assignments are done in right-to-left order. So we could translate it literally to use an `if` statement and a temp variable:

```
// Fetch grades[item.Grade] and save it in temp
var temp = grades[item.Grade];
if( ! temp ) {
    // It was missing, so use an empty object as the default value
    temp = {};
}
// Now save the result in grades[item.Grade] (in case it was missing)
// and in grade
grades[item.Grade] = temp;
var grade = temp;
```

You may notice that in the case where `grades[item.Grade]` already exists, we take the value we just fetched and store it back into the same property. This is unnecessary, of course, and  you probably wouldn't do it if you were writing the code out like this. Instead, you would simplify it:

```
var grade = grades[item.Grade];
if( ! grade ) {
    grade = grades[item.Grade] = {};
}
```

That would be a perfectly reasonable way to write the same code, and it's more efficient too. It also gives you a way to do a more specific test than the "truthiness" that the `||` idiom relies on. For example instead of `if( ! grade )` you might want to use `if( grade === undefined )`.

Comment: This is very close to what I need. How would you modify this to make the result a simple array in the form of [grade,domain,domain,grade,domain,domain,grade,domain]?

Comment: The array format you're asking about here doesn't sound practical at all. How do you distinguish between grades and domains when they are intermixed like that? It would be very hard to work with. It's easy to turn this `grades` object into any format you want, or to work with directly and call any kind of functions as needed with the data. But don't get hung up on a data format like that array which just won't work. The real question to ask is what you want to do with the data from there.

Comment: But if you want the output format you asked about in the original question, that's easy. I updated the answer with a few lines of code to generate that format.

Comment: I'm hoping to generate some html with the Grade as the header and the Domains unique to that grade as on unordered list below it. I was thinking the array would let me inject some html tags in between and create an html string. Like this ["<div>Grade1<li>Domain1</li><li>Domain2</li></div><div>Grade2<li>Domain1</li> etc..."]

Comment: @MichaelGeary Could you please explain the logic of `var grade = grades[item.Grade] = grades[item.Grade] || {};`?

Comment: @Rai Sure thing, I added a note at the end of the answer explaining it.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 42):

I know there are many answers already but the best one that worked for me for a complex json structure is:

```js
var arr = [{ "State": "RWCW", "desc": "WEST", "code": "RWCW", "level": 0, "save": "RWCW : WEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RSCW", "desc": "SOUTHEAST", "code": "RSCW", "level": 0, "save": "RSCW : SOUTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RCSW", "desc": "SOUTHWEST", "code": "RCSW", "level": 0, "save": "RCSW : SOUTHWEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RECW", "desc": "NORTHEAST", "code": "RECW", "level": 0, "save": "RECW : NORTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RWCW", "desc": "WEST", "code": "RWCW", "level": 0, "save": "RWCW : WEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RWCW", "desc": "WEST", "code": "RWCW", "level": 0, "save": "RWCW : WEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RSCW", "desc": "SOUTHEAST", "code": "RSCW", "level": 0, "save": "RSCW : SOUTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RCSW", "desc": "SOUTHWEST", "code": "RCSW", "level": 0, "save": "RCSW : SOUTHWEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RECW", "desc": "NORTHEAST", "code": "RECW", "level": 0, "save": "RECW : NORTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RWCW", "desc": "WEST", "code": "RWCW", "level": 0, "save": "RWCW : WEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RSCW", "desc": "SOUTHEAST", "code": "RSCW", "level": 0, "save": "RSCW : SOUTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RECW", "desc": "NORTHEAST", "code": "RECW", "level": 0, "save": "RECW : NORTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RWCW", "desc": "WEST", "code": "RWCW", "level": 0, "save": "RWCW : WEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RCSW", "desc": "SOUTHWEST", "code": "RCSW", "level": 0, "save": "RCSW : SOUTHWEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RWCW", "desc": "WEST", "code": "RWCW", "level": 0, "save": "RWCW : WEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RCNW", "desc": "MIDWEST", "code": "RCNW", "level": 0, "save": "RCNW : MIDWEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RCSW", "desc": "SOUTHWEST", "code": "RCSW", "level": 0, "save": "RCSW : SOUTHWEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RECW", "desc": "NORTHEAST", "code": "RECW", "level": 0, "save": "RECW : NORTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RCNW", "desc": "MIDWEST", "code": "RCNW", "level": 0, "save": "RCNW : MIDWEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RSCW", "desc": "SOUTHEAST", "code": "RSCW", "level": 0, "save": "RSCW : SOUTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RECW", "desc": "NORTHEAST", "code": "RECW", "level": 0, "save": "RECW : NORTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RCNW", "desc": "MIDWEST", "code": "RCNW", "level": 0, "save": "RCNW : MIDWEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RSCW", "desc": "SOUTHEAST", "code": "RSCW", "level": 0, "save": "RSCW : SOUTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RSCW", "desc": "SOUTHEAST", "code": "RSCW", "level": 0, "save": "RSCW : SOUTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RSCW", "desc": "SOUTHEAST", "code": "RSCW", "level": 0, "save": "RSCW : SOUTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RCNW", "desc": "MIDWEST", "code": "RCNW", "level": 0, "save": "RCNW : MIDWEST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RSCW", "desc": "SOUTHEAST", "code": "RSCW", "level": 0, "save": "RSCW : SOUTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }, { "State": "RECW", "desc": "NORTHEAST", "code": "RECW", "level": 0, "save": "RECW : NORTHEAST", "attribute1": "", "attribute2": "" }];

var clean = arr.filter((arr, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex((t) => (t.save === arr.save && t.State === arr.State)))

console.log(clean);
```

You can try this directly to chrome browser console and edit according to your need.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is great! I think using inbuilt functions are efficient than using foreach. :)

Answer (score 29):

```
function arrUnique(arr) {
    var cleaned = [];
    arr.forEach(function(itm) {
        var unique = true;
        cleaned.forEach(function(itm2) {
            if (_.isEqual(itm, itm2)) unique = false;
        });
        if (unique)  cleaned.push(itm);
    });
    return cleaned;
}

var standardsList = arrUnique(standardsList);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5TRqF/1/)

This will return

```
var standardsList = [
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"}
];
```

Which is exactly what you asked for ?

Comment: what do you say for performance part, if I have long list of json (at least 500 json, with 10 property each).

Answer (score 13):

I needed to do some de-duping of JSON objects so I stumbled across this page. However, I went with the short ES6 solution (no need for external libs), running this in Chrome Dev Tools Snippets:

```
const data = [ /* any list of objects */ ];
const set = new Set(data.map(item => JSON.stringify(item)));
const dedup = [...set].map(item => JSON.parse(item));
console.log(`Removed ${data.length - dedup.length} elements`);
console.log(dedup);
```

Answer (score 8):

Reviving an old question, but I wanted to post an iteration on @adeneo's answer. That answer is completely general, but for this use case it could be more efficient (it's slow on my machine with an array of a few thousand objects). If you know the specific properties of the objects you need to compare, just compare them directly:

```
var sl = standardsList;
var out = [];

for (var i = 0, l = sl.length; i < l; i++) {
    var unique = true;
    for (var j = 0, k = out.length; j < k; j++) {
        if ((sl[i].Grade === out[j].Grade) && (sl[i].Domain === out[j].Domain)) {
            unique = false;
        }
    }
    if (unique) {
        out.push(sl[i]);
    }
}

console.log(sl.length); // 10
console.log(out.length); // 5
```

Comment: best answer here, imo

Answer (score 6):

Javascript solution for your case:

```
console.log(unique(standardsList));

function unique(obj){
    var uniques=[];
    var stringify={};
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
       var keys=Object.keys(obj[i]);
       keys.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});
       var str='';
        for(var j=0;j<keys.length;j++){
           str+= JSON.stringify(keys[j]);
           str+= JSON.stringify(obj[i][keys[j]]);
        }
        if(!stringify.hasOwnProperty(str)){
            uniques.push(obj[i]);
            stringify[str]=true;
        }
    }
    return uniques;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
var standardsList = [
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"}
];

standardsList = standardsList.filter((li, idx, self) => self.map(itm => itm.Grade+itm.Domain).indexOf(li.Grade+li.Domain) === idx)

document.write(JSON.stringify(standardsList))
```

here is a functional way of doing it that is much easier

```
standardsList = standardsList.filter((li, idx, self) => self.map(itm => iem.Grade+itm.domain).indexOf(li.Grade+li.domain) === idx)
```

Comment: standardsList = standardsList.filter((li, idx, self) => self.map(itm => itm.Grade+itm.domain).indexOf(li.Grade+li.domain) === idx)

Answer (score 5):

**The following method does the way you want. It filters the array based on all properties values.
**

```
    var standardsList = [
  { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" },
  { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" },
  { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" },
  { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" },
  { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry" },
  { "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" },
  { "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" },
  { "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation" },
  { "Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry" },
  { "Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry" }
];

const removeDupliactes = (values) => {
  let concatArray = values.map(eachValue => {
    return Object.values(eachValue).join('')
  })
  let filterValues = values.filter((value, index) => {
    return concatArray.indexOf(concatArray[index]) === index

  })
  return filterValues
}
removeDupliactes(standardsList)
```

**Results this**

```
[{Grade: "Math K", Domain: "Counting & Cardinality"}

{Grade: "Math K", Domain: "Geometry"}

{Grade: "Math 1", Domain: "Counting & Cardinality"}

{Grade: "Math 1", Domain: "Orders of Operation"}

{Grade: "Math 2", Domain: "Geometry"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to remove the duplicates. (For new readers)

```js
var standardsList = [
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"}
];

var grades = new Map();
standardsList.forEach( function( item ) {
    grades.set(JSON.stringify(item), item);
});

console.log( [...grades.values()]);

/*
[
  { Grade: 'Math K', Domain: 'Counting & Cardinality' },
  { Grade: 'Math K', Domain: 'Geometry' },
  { Grade: 'Math 1', Domain: 'Counting & Cardinality' },
  { Grade: 'Math 1', Domain: 'Orders of Operation' },
  { Grade: 'Math 2', Domain: 'Geometry' }
]
*/
```

Comment: This was awesome, I had to take these results and push them back into a new array after it ran through this, but it's PERFECT

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
_.uniq(standardsList, JSON.stringify)
```

This would probably be slow for very long lists, however.

Comment: stringifying the object is no guarantee that the objects will be the same. Keys and values out of order would cause a mismatch.

Comment: You could sort each individual items to give them a standard format to get around the problem @adeneo mention. Then you could stringify the items, run _.uniq and then destringify them.

Comment: @Leo - you can't sort an object.

Comment: @adeneo You are right, but I did not mean it literally.

Comment: If you didn't mean it literally, then how will it help when stringifying them?

Comment: @cookiemonster Just create a temporary object for each individual item  with the key/values in some sort order. (There are many ways to do that, of course.) Then stringify that object.

Comment: That wouldn't work for nested objects though without some pretty involved code. There is probably some good solution with _.isEqual

Comment: Good point, @stubailo, but it would work with items similar to those in the question.

Comment: And it looks like _.isEqual can do the job (but it could indeed be slow, perhaps).

Answer (score 3):

I found here every answer is so expensive to compute, So we need an answer that is:

- Efficient
- Short & Elegant
- And easy to compute.

#### By using map

```js
let standardsList = [{ "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry" }, { "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation" }, { "Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry" }, { "Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry" }],
    map = {};

for (let list of standardsList) {
    map[Object.values(list).join('')] = list;
}
console.log('Using Map', Object.values(map));
```

#### By using set

```js
let standardsList = [{ "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry" }, { "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality" }, { "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation" }, { "Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry" }, { "Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry" }],
    set = new Set, results = [];

for (let list of standardsList) {
    let id = Object.values(list).join('');
    if (!set.has(id)) {
        set.add(id);
        results.push(list);
    }
}
console.log('Using Set', results);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var standardsList = [
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"}
];          

 function uniqurArray(array){
                         var a = array.concat();
                        for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                            for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; j++) {
                                if(a[i].Grade === a[j].Grade){
                                    a.splice(j--, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        return a;
                    }

    uniqurArray(standardsList) // put this js in console and you get uniq object in array
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash, [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniq)  (4.17.15)

Example code:

```
var object = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];

_.uniqWith(object, _.isEqual);

// => [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }]
```

Comment: This approach also works with Underscore out of the box: `_.uniq(object, _.isEqual)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to do this very concisely with Underscore out of the box. The first was already mentioned by cookie monster in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507853/remove-duplicate-objects-from-json-array#comment36053939_23507853) directly under the question:

```js
_.uniq(standardsList, item => item.Grade + item.Domain)
```

With direct string concatenation as shown above, problematic edge cases could potentially occur in situations like the following:

```js
var standardsList = [
    {Grade: 'abcdef', Domain: 'ghi'},
    {Grade: 'abc', Domain: 'defghi'}
];
```

since both produce the combined string `'abcdefghi'` despite them not being equivalent. The simplest solution to this is to interject a substring that you know never occurs as a suffix of the Grade (or as a prefix of the Domain), for example assuming that `': '` is such a substring:

```js
_.uniq(standardsList, item => item.Grade + ': ' + item.Domain)
```

The second was already mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62890078/1166087) by dpmemcry. Here is the version that is compatible with Underscore:

```js
_.uniq(standardsList, _.isEqual);
```

The difference is that the first solution only takes the fields into account that you specifically select, while the second takes *all* fields into account and even performs a recursive comparison. In some cases, this may be exactly what you want, while in other cases, it might be too expensive.

With a bit more effort, i.e., by writing a custom helper function, you can achieve a compromise between these solutions where you can select the fields that are taken into account without having to write out a concatenation expression every time. Here is one possible way to write that helper function:

```js
function byFields(fields, separator) {
    return function(item) {
        return _.map(fields, _.propertyOf(item)).join(separator);
    };
}
```

and here is how you use it:

```js
_.uniq(standardsList, byFields(['Grade', 'Domain'], ': '));
```

With this latter approach, you also have the option to perform selective deep comparisons by passing array paths instead of strings in the list of fields. This lets you have deep property lookups without forcing you to recurse all the way through each object. For example, suppose that the `Domain` property of each item is a nested object, like this:

```js
var standardsList = [
    {Grade: "Math K", Domain: {id: 1, name: "Counting & Cardinality"}},
    // ...
];
```

Then you could use the above helper function like this, without modification:

```js
_.uniq(standardsList, byFields['Grade', ['Domain', 'id']], ': '));
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across a solution to this online a few months ago but can't remember the source. Credits to the author. The solution works as below.

```
// Example use case
const students = [
    {
        "m_name": "Jason",
        "m_id": "1",
        "age": 18,
        "subject": "Biology"
    },
    {
        "m_name": "Jason",
        "m_id": "1",
        "age": 18,
        "subject": "Chemistry"
    },
    {
        "m_name": "Sameer",
        "m_id": "2",
        "age": 18,
        "subject": "English"
    },
    {
        "m_name": "Sameer",
        "m_id": "2",
        "age": 18,
        "subject": "History"
    },
    {
        "m_name": "Philip",
        "m_id": "3",
        "age": 18,
        "subject": "Drama"
    }
]

// Function to merge by student name (or ID)
const groupBy = key => array =>
    array.reduce((objectByKeyValue, obj) => {
        const value = obj[key];
        objectByKeyValue[value] = (objectByKeyValue[value] || []).concat(obj);
        return objectByKeyValue;
    }, {});

// Replace with the key name
const groupBy_StudentName = groupBy('m_name') // or groupBy('m_id')

// Now pass your array name here
const grouped = groupBy_StudentName(students)

// Check your answer
console.log(grouped)

// Output

{
    "Jason": [
        {
            m_name: 'Jason',
            m_id: '1',
            age: 18,
            subject: 'Biology'
        },
        {
            m_name: 'Jason',
            m_id: '1',
            age: 18,
            subject: 'Chemistry'
        }
    ],
        "Sameer": [
            {
                m_name: 'Sameer',
                m_id: '2',
                age: 18,
                subject: 'English'
            },
            {
                m_name: 'Sameer',
                m_id: '2',
                age: 18,
                subject: 'History'
            }
        ],
            "Philip": [
                {
                    m_name: 'Philip',
                    m_id: '3',
                    age: 18,
                    subject: 'Drama'
                }
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var standardsList = [
                          { Grade: "Math K", Domain: "Counting & Cardinality" },
                          { Grade: "Math K", Domain: "Counting & Cardinality" },
                          { Grade: "Math K", Domain: "Counting & Cardinality" },
                          { Grade: "Math K", Domain: "Counting & Cardinality" },
                          { Grade: "Math K", Domain: "Geometry" },
                          { Grade: "Math 1", Domain: "Counting & Cardinality" },
                          { Grade: "Math 1", Domain: "Counting & Cardinality" },
                          { Grade: "Math 1", Domain: "Orders of Operation" },
                          { Grade: "Math 2", Domain: "Geometry" },
                          { Grade: "Math 2", Domain: "Geometry" },
                         ];
    let fUArr = standardsList.filter(
        (li, idx, self) =>
          self
            .map((itm) =>
              Object.values(itm)
                .reduce((r, c) => r.concat(c), '')
            )
            .indexOf(
              Object.values(li)
                .reduce((r, c) => r.concat(c), '')
            ) === idx
      );
      console.log(fUArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Pseudocode

```
var standardsList = [
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"}
];
var newArr =[]
for(var i in standardsList){
    newArr.push(JSON.stringify(standardsList[i]))
}
var obj = {};
newArr= newArr.filter((item)=>{
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (obj[item] = true);
})
standardsList.length = 0
for(var i in newArr){
    standardsList.push(JSON.parse(newArr[i]))
}
console.log(standardsList)
```

I have choose a sample array similar to yours. Its easier to compare objects once you stringfy them. Then you just have to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short one-liner with es6!

```
const nums = [
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC9233F2015",
  "AC9233F2015",
  "AC9233F2015",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC9233F2015",
  "AC9233F2015",
  "AC9233F2015",
  "AC9233F2015",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC9233F2015",
  "AC9233F2015",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC8818E2",
  "ACB098F25",
  "ACB098F25",
  "ACB098F25",
  "ACB098F25",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC8818E2",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  "AC8818E1",
  ]
```

Set is a new data object introduced in ES6.
  Because Set only lets you store unique values. When you pass in an array, it will remove any duplicate values.

```
export const $uniquenums = [...new Set(nums)].sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem with *nomaed* [...set] solution (which is the one I liked most and tried first): If for whatever reason, the object is not quite the same (i.e., any of its attributes is missing or different), it is not dedup'd. Semantically, that might be right; but at times this is a plausible scenario and still want to dedup based on a key.

This is my solution, using map and array functions in a single line:

```
arr = arr.filter( (elem, ix) => arr.findIndex( elem1 => elem1.myFld == elem.myFld ) === ix );
```

where:

- arr: is the array of JSON objects to be dedup'd
- elem: is the iterator for the filter function of arrays
- ix: is the index of the element of the arary when iterating
- elem1: is the iterator of a "second" (nested) iteration to compare fields
- myFld: is the field based on which the dedup' will occur

All what it does, is to eliminate those elements where field "myField" is not in the index where it is first found (using "findIndex" function of jSon's array; which is kind of equivalent to "indexOf" in single objects arrays).

Try it like this:

```
arr = [ {fld1:"first", val:1}, {fld1:"second", val:2}, {fld1:"third", val:3}, {fld1:"fourth", val:4},
        {fld1:"fifth", val:5}, {fld1:"second", val:6}, {fld1:"fourth", val:7 } ];
// note that repeated objects, vary in its second field "val". In a practical scenario this might not be the case
console.log("with duplicates: " + JSON.stringify(arr));

// This is the only dedup' line!
arr = arr.filter( (elem, ix) => arr.findIndex( elem1 => elem1.fld1 == elem.fld1 ) === ix ); 
console.log("dedup'd: " + JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone need, this is the solution I use to return unique value given a primary key.

```js
var standardsList = [
    {"id": 1, "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"id": 1, "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"id": 1, "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"id": 1, "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"id": 2, "Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"id": 3, "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"id": 3, "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
    {"id": 4, "Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation"},
    {"id": 5, "Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"},
    {"id": 5, "Grade": "Math 2", "Domain": "Geometry"}
];

function uniqueByKey(array, key) {
    return [...new Map(array.map((x) => [x[key], x])).values()];
}

console.log(uniqueByKey(standardsList, 'id'))
```