# Extracting data from a JSON call to a Postgres table for use in Highcharts (without PHP)

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, highcharts

I am using JSON to retrieve data from a Postgres table for use in a Highcharts column chart.  I have five time-series in the database, each with five elements, and only want to use two key:value pairs from each time-series in a chart.

The output needs to be in this format:

An array of objects with named values. In this case the objects are point configuration objects as seen below.

Range series values are given by low and high.

Example:

```
data: [{
          name: 'Point 1',
          color: '#00FF00',
          y: 0
      }, {
          name: 'Point 2',
          color: '#FF00FF',
          y: 5
      }]
```

Note that line series and derived types like spline and area, require data to be sorted by X because it interpolates mouse coordinates for the tooltip. Column and scatter series, where each point has its own mouse event, does not require sorting.

That's taken from the Highcharts series / data api: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Here's my db schema:

```
enable_extension "plpgsql"

create_table "series", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "acronym"
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "current"
  t.string   "previous"
  t.string   "pc1"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
end
```

Here's the json call:

```
url = "http://local server 3000/series";
$.getJSON(url, function (series) {
    console.log(series);
    }
    options.series[0].data = series;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

console.log shows an array of objects being returned:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
acronym: "1"
current: "3.4"
id: 1
name: "a"
pc1: "25"
previous: "2.4"
url: "http://localhost:3000/series/1.json"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I "opened" the first object in order to show how the data is being returned.  Notice that the key:value pairs are not followed by a comma (which Highcharts asks for).

In the current chart, a column chart, I only want to display the series "name", e.g., "a", and the value of the corresponding key / value pair "pc1".  (They're actually going to be economic time series, e.g., CPI, and its year-over-year percent change.)  I plan on creating other charts with, for example, the current and previous values, for a particular time series.

I'm new to programming and do not know how to "extract", if you will, the key:value pairs into the Highcharts format.

I tried pushing the data into a new array with no luck:

```
var data = [];
data.push(series[0].name + "," series[0].pc1);
```

I tried a for loop with no luck:

```
for (var i = 0, l = series.length; i < l; i++) {
var key = series[i].name;
var value = series[i].pc1;
var data = [ [key + ":" + value], };
```

In most attempts, I could build an array, but not a nested one of objects and / or one with the comma between x and y values.

I also tried splice(); however, could only remove entire objects.

So, how do I get output that looks like:

```
data: [{
name: 'a',
pc1: '25',
}, {
name: 'b',
pc1: '15',
}]
```

I see some very complex code in the answers relating to PHP and MySQL; however, there's nothing with JSON alone (that I could find).

A related question: Am I approaching the problem correctly.  Or should I, perhaps, create a new database table for each chart so that only the data I want to display is saved and retrieved.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely **not** recommend you create a new database table for each chart. That is not necessary. You can tailor your *SQL* queries from that table to suit your chart data needs.

One issue is that your y-value is currently a string, which is not what you want in a graphing application. That should be cast to an integer in your SQL query.

The data form is an *array* of *hashes*. To initialize the array and add one such element, you could do something like this:

```
data = [];
data.push({'name': 'a', 'pc1': 25});
```

To see the data in pretty-printed form, you can verify it in the *console* with this code:

```
print(JSON.stringify(data));
```

So, basically you can build up the *array* of *hashes* in the for loop (or via a mechanism  such as *jQuery's* `$.each`).

That method is essentially hand-rolling your own *JSON*, though, which is kind of tedious and can be error-prone in some cases. An easier method would probably be to have your backend convert the result of the *Postgres* query to JSON directly.

*Ruby* (which I assume is what you're using in the backend based on your schema definition code) has a *JSON* module (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) that can do this.

Note that for this to work, your *Postgres* library will need to return the data as an *array* of *hashes*, so it has the column names as well (just an *array* of *arrays* will not work). This is doable through libraries such as *psycopg2* (*Python*) and *DBI* (*Perl*), and is likely similarly available in the *Ruby* library you're using also.

Comment: Ken, That was a big help and got me thinking further about the issue.  I also stumbled into this SO question: Remove Duplicate objects from JSON array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507853/remove-duplicate-objects-from-json-array