# removing duplicates from JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JS array:

```
var items=[
    { id: 1, name: 'aa' },
    { id: 1, name: 'bb' },
    { id: 2, name: 'cc' },
    { id: 1, name: 'dd' }
];
```

I wan to convert it to the following.

```
var items=[
    { id: 1, name: 'dd' },
    { id: 2, name: 'cc' }
];
```

How should I go about it using JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507853/remove-duplicate-objects-from-json-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could actually do this quite simply, just looping over it. For each item, assign its place in the new array corresponding to its ID. Earlier IDs get overwritten, so only the last one is saved.

```js
var items=[
    { id: 1, name: 'aa' },
    { id: 1, name: 'bb' },
    { id: 2, name: 'cc' },
    { id: 1, name: 'dd' }
], newItems = [];
for (var i =0;i<items.length;i++){
    newItems[items[i].id - 1] = items[i];
}
alert(JSON.stringify(newItems));
```

Comment: What if ID was not contiguous?

Comment: @Adam Then there'll be a few empty list items. Those can easily be filtered out.

Comment: @Scimonster - it's a great solutions but, if you want to filtered out  data on the bases of any string data than it'll not work.

Comment: @user3577774 in that case, you can use an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
items = items.reverse().filter((function() {
    var existing = {};
    return function(item) {
        if(existing[item.id]) {
            return false;
        }
        existing[item.id] = true;
        return item;
    }
}()));
```

Comment: Since we are filtering, yes, let's use `filter`!! The inside could be cleaned up a little bit, however. How about `return !existing[item.id] && existing[item.id] = true;`?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
var items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'aa' },
    { id: 1, name: 'bb' },
    { id: 2, name: 'cc' },
    { id: 1, name: 'dd' }
];

function removeDupIds(items){
    var result  = [],
        uniqIds = {},
        i       = 0,
        l       = items.length;

    for(; i<l; i++){
        uniqIds[items[i].id] = items[i].name;
    }

    for(var k in uniqIds){
        result.push({id: k, name: uniqIds[k]});
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(removeDupIds(items));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore, it would just be

```
_.uniq(items.reverse(), function(i1, i2) { return i1.id === i2.id; }))
```

Normally `_.uniq` removes identical items, but we can pass it the second parameter specifying a function to use to determine if two items are going to be considered identical.

The `items.reverse()` is needed because the OP seems to want the final item to take priority.