# Removing duplicates from JSON array by a value in each JSON object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

**If there are two JSON objects in an array with same value for a particular field, then I want to mark them as duplicate**. I want to remove one of them. Similarly, when there are multiple duplicate, I only want to keep the last object(latest).If this is input:

```
names_array = [
    {name: "a",  age: 15},
    {name: "a",  age: 16},
    {name: "a",  age: 17},
    {name: "b",  age: 18}
    {name: "b",  age: 19}];
```

I want the output to be

```
names_array_new = 
    {name: "a",  age: 17},
    {name: "b",  age: 19}];
```

I have searched for this but only found how to remove duplicates when entire objects are same.

Comment: Check this: [How to Remove Duplicate objects from JSON Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507853/remove-duplicate-objects-from-json-array)

it may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. This was also helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
names_array = [
    {name: "a",  age: 15},
    {name: "a",  age: 16},
    {name: "a",  age: 17},
    {name: "b",  age: 18},
    {name: "b",  age: 19}];

function hash(o){
    return o.name;
}    

var hashesFound = {};

names_array.forEach(function(o){
    hashesFound[hash(o)] = o;
})

var results = Object.keys(hashesFound).map(function(k){
    return hashesFound[k];
})
```

The `hash` function decides which objects are duplicates, the `hashesFound` object stores each hash value together with the latest object that produced that hash, and the `results` array contains the matching objects.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:

```js
var names_array = [
    { name: "a", age: 15 },
    { name: "a", age: 16 },
    { name: "a", age: 17 },
    { name: "b", age: 18 },
    { name: "b", age: 19 }
];

var names_array_new = names_array.reduceRight(function (r, a) {
    r.some(function (b) { return a.name === b.name; }) || r.push(a);
    return r;
}, []);

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(names_array_new, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names_array = [
{name: "a", age: 15},
{name: "a", age: 16},
{name: "a", age: 17},
{name: "b", age: 18},
{name: "b", age: 19}];

function removeDuplicate(arr, prop) {
var new_arr = [];
var lookup = {};
for (var i in arr) {
    lookup[arr[i][prop]] = arr[i];
}
for (i in lookup) {
    new_arr.push(lookup[i]);
}
return new_arr;}
var newArray = removeDuplicate(names_array, 'name');
console.log("Result "+newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.from(new Set(brand.map(obj => JSON.stringify(obj)))).map(item => JSON.parse(item))

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.