# Remove duplicate values from json array using angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I want to remove duplicates from the following json array

```
$scope.array = [
    {"name":"aaa","key":"1"},
    {"name":"bbb","key":"2"},
    {"name":"aaa","key":"1"},
    {"name":"ccc","key":"3"},
    {"name":"bbb","key":"2"}
];
```

I tried following code but its not working

```
var ids = {};

$scope.array.forEach(function (list) {
    ids[list.name] = (ids[list.name] || 0) + 1;
});

var finalResult = [];
$scope.array.forEach(function (list) {
    if (ids[list.name] === 1) finalResult.push(student);
});

console.log(finalResult);
```

This is the expected result.

```
$scope.array = [
    {"name":"aaa","key":"1"},
    {"name":"bbb","key":"2"} ,
    {"name":"ccc","key":"3"} 
];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicate objects from JSON Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507853/remove-duplicate-objects-from-json-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```js
$scope = {};
$scope.array = [{
  "name": "aaa",
  "key": "1"
}, {
  "name": "bbb",
  "key": "2"
}, {
  "name": "aaa",
  "key": "1"
}, {
  "name": "ccc",
  "key": "3"
}, {
  "name": "bbb",
  "key": "2"
}];

var ids = {};

$scope.array = $scope.array.filter(function(v) {
  var ind = v.name + '_' + v.key;
  if (!ids[ind]) {
    ids[ind] = true;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
console.log($scope.array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unique filter.

```
<tr ng-repeat="arr in array | unique: 'key'" >
   <td> {{ arr.name }} , {{ arr.key }} </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
$scope.array = = [{
    "testada": "ecom",
        "id": "27"
}, {
    "testada": "alorta",
        "id": "27"
}, {
    "testada": "france24",
        "id": "23"
}, {
    "testada": "seloger",
        "id": "23"
}];

var arr = [],
    collection = [];

$scope.array.forEach(json_all, function (index, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value.id, arr) == -1) {
        arr.push(value.id);
        collection.push(value);
    }
});

console.log(json_all);
console.log(collection);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.array = [
        {"name":"aaa","key":"1"},
        {"name":"bbb","key":"2"},
        {"name":"aaa","key":"1"},
        {"name":"ccc","key":"3"},
        {"name":"bbb","key":"2"}
    ];

    var newArr = [];  //this will be new array with no duplicate value
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.array.length; i++) {

        if(!ifContains($scope.array[i])){
            newArr.push($scope.array[i]);
        }
    }

    function ifContains(obj){
        debugger
        var flag = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
            if(newArr[i].name == obj.name && newArr[i].key == obj.key )
                return true;
            else
                flag = false;
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be very simply done by pure JS. An invention of `Object.prototype.compare()` will help us enormously. Let's see how it works;

```js
Object.prototype.compare = function(o){
  var ok = Object.keys(this);
  return typeof o === "object" && ok.length === Object.keys(o).length ? ok.every(k => this[k] === o[k]) : false;
};
var myArray = [
    {"name":"aaa","key":"1"},
    {"name":"bbb","key":"2"},
    {"name":"aaa","key":"1"},
    {"name":"ccc","key":"3"},
    {"name":"bbb","key":"2"}
],
filtered = myArray.reduce((p,c) => p.findIndex(f => c.compare(f)) == -1 ? p.concat(c) : p,[]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

Note: `Object.prototype.compare()` v.01 won't do deep object comparison as of now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniqueList = _.uniq($scope.array, function (item) {
            return item.key;
 });
 console.log(uniqueList);
```

use underscore.js, anyone helps out so post later.

Answer (score -1):

you can use pure javascript!

```
uniqueArray = a.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return a.indexOf(item) == pos;
})
```

in your case:

```
var finalResult = [];
finalResult = $scope.array.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return array.indexOf(item) == pos;
})
```