# how to check same value in object and filter them on another key basis which is unique

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I'm hoping someone has come across this problem also. I'm a newbie to all this, therefore excuse my lack of knowledge in advance.

I have my json like this

```
[{"latitude":22.7169,"longitude":75.8687,"severity":"Open","severityStatus":"TROUBLE","macAddress":"00:00:00:00:02:13","informationSeverity":null,"truobleSeverity":null,"status":"Open"},{"latitude":22.7169,"longitude":75.8687,"severity":"New","severityStatus":"CRITICAL","macAddress":"01:03:00:55:12:00","informationSeverity":null,"truobleSeverity":null,"status":"New"}]
```

All I need is to filter them on the basis of having same latitude and longitude and if they have same lat and long then I have to make a condition that the severitystatus whose defined trouble should be push rather than critical. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicate objects from JSON Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507853/remove-duplicate-objects-from-json-array)

Comment: What should be the output ?

Comment: _.filter(arr, (el) => { return el.status == "TROUBLE" })

Comment: @Weedoze its output should take object which severitystatus is trouble all i need is to take only those object whose severity status is high in case when latitude and longitude is same

Comment: @HarshBatham Only the object where `status=="TROUBLE"` ?