# how to find duplicate json element in object in side object of array list?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have json array ob object list name of array is value in this array i have on inside value object i have another object called filed i want access filed object and find duplicate any help?.
**Update: i used System.out.println("a : " + Collections.frequency(stringList, "Accounts Receivable")); method but its give me 0 always**

```
{
"",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": """,
        "createdDateTime": "",
        "eTag": """,
        "id": "",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "",
        "webUrl": "",
        "createdBy": {
            "user": {
                "email": "",
                "id": "",
                "displayName": ""
            }
        },
        "lastModifiedBy": {
            "user": {
                "email": ",
                "id": "",
                "displayName": ""
            }
        },
        "parentReference": {},
        "contentType": {
            "id": ""
        },
        "fields@odata.context": "",
        "fields": {
            "@odata.etag": """,
            "id": "",
            "ContentType": "",
            "Modified": "",
            "Created": "",
            "AuthorLookupId": "",
            "EditorLookupId": "",
            "_UIVersionString": "",
            "Attachments": false,
            "Edit": "",
            "ItemChildCount": "0",
            "FolderChildCount": "0",
            "_ComplianceFlags": "",
            "_ComplianceTag": "",
            "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
            "_ComplianceTagUserId": "",
            "JobCategory": "",--> "check this value for duplicate"
            "Competency": "",
            "Level": "",
            "CompetencyType": "",
            "Index": "0",
            "FormID@odata.type": "",
            "FormID": 25
        }
    }]
```

in side value array list there is fields object but while trying its given only object here is my Code.

```
   Set<Example> uniqueSet = new HashSet<Example>(borrowModelList);

            for (Example temp : uniqueSet) {


                txtInfo.setText(String.valueOf(Collections.frequency(borrowModelList,temp.getValue().get(0).getFields())));
                textInfoOne.setText(String.valueOf(Collections.frequency(borrowModelList,temp.getValue().get(0).getFields())));
                textInfoTwo.setText(String.valueOf(Collections.frequency(borrowModelList,temp.getValue().get(0).getFields())));
                textInfoThree.setText(String.valueOf(Collections.frequency(borrowModelList,temp.getValue().get(0).getFields())));
                textInfoFour.setText(String.valueOf(Collections.frequency(borrowModelList,temp.getValue().get(0).getFields())));
            }
```

**I/System.out:  1**
in side field object there is JobCategory field i want to check only and show on textview.

Comment: You misunderstood the first parameter in [Collections#frequency​(Collection<?> c, Object o)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-). It should be `exampleList.get(0).getFields()`.

Comment: 1) what is your _number duplicate element_? Is this a field in json or says which object is duplicated or how many duplicates of an object occure?

Comment: i hove 15 object in side value and each value has field object

Comment: @P.Juni pleas check my edit code i am not able to access filed object inside value array list

Comment: @P.Juni any Suggestion on this

Comment: i'm afraid, i can't fully understand how do you want to check if the duplicates occure. Do you want to get some specific field from an object and then check if it occures more than once in the whole json? Is so, what is the field

Comment: i have so many duplicate value inside field object so i want to check duplicate value in field object only.

Comment: @P.Juni do you want all json data to see?

Comment: @P.Juni  please check my edit code i want to check field object value only and display it.

Comment: can any one give me suggestion on this.

Comment: @P.Juni do you have any suggestion?

Comment: sorry not really :(

Comment: Any body give me any suggestion what here i missed.

Comment: @007 r u using rest api or soap service, if u r using rest api then in server side code u can restrict the duplicate records, and once see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507853/remove-duplicate-objects-from-json-array. Thank you

Comment: @Varma  its sharepoint rest api.

Comment: @Varma no aculty requirment is like that i have to cont number of duplcate value and show into textview. but while using hashmap its not reading inner object i think that is issue.

Comment: @007 see this link https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/06/3-ways-to-find-duplicate-elements-in-array-java.html, replace  // your duplicate element with count variable. thank u

Comment: @Varma i tryied alradey but its example about simple array i have inner object and control not read that.

Comment: @007 copy u r json values to individual array and then check y u r struggling this much