# How to filter out duplicates from a nested object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I currently have a nested geojson array with duplicate values. How can I filter out these values based on the OBJECT ID?

```
let geojson = [
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249646, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}}, 
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249646, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}}, 
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249647, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}},
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249647, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}},
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249648, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}},
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249649, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}} 
  ]
```

What I would like to return is a json array with unique values, like this:

```
[ 
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249646, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}}, 
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249647, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}},
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249648, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}},
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249649, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}} 
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507853/remove-duplicate-objects-from-json-array  check this post - you'll get hopefully  your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `reduce` alongside `Object.values()`:

```js
let geojson = [
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249646, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}}, 
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249646, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}}, 
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249647, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}},
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249647, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}},
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249648, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}},
  {properties: {OBJECTID: 6249649, FeatureCode: 10185, Version: 3, VersionDate: "1/25/2018"}} 
]

const out = Object.values(geojson.reduce((a, v) => (a[v.properties.OBJECTID] = v, a), {}))
console.log(out)
```