# Reduce JSON array to object with combined key-values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reduce

I have an array like this:

```json
[
    { "avl_res": 1, "res_status": "Available", "code": "AAA" },
    { "avl_res": 2, "res_status": "Unavailable", "code": "AAA" },
    { "avl_res": 2, "res_status": "Available", "code": "BBB" },
    { "avl_res": 1, "res_status": "Available", "code": "CCC" },
    { "avl_res": 5, "res_status": "Unavailable", "code": "CCC" },
    { "avl_res": 3, "res_status": "Unavailable", "code": "DDD" },
];
```

I am trying to produce this:

```json
[
    {"avl_res":1,"total_res":3,"code":"AAA"},
    {"avl_res":2,"total_res":2,"code":"BBB"},
    {"avl_res":1,"total_res":6,"code":"CCC"},
    {"avl_res":0,"total_res":3,"code":"DDD"},
];
```

Following the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507853/remove-duplicate-objects-from-json-array), I managed to do it with this:

```js
var singles = {};
arr.forEach(function (item) {
    var single = singles[item.code] = singles[item.code] || {};
    single[item.res_status] = item.avl_res;
});

var outputList = [];
for (var single in singles) {
    let total_res = 0;
    let avl_res = 0;

    singles[single]['Available'] ? avl_res = singles[single]['Available'] : avl_res = 0;
    singles[single]['Unavailable'] ? total_res = avl_res + singles[single]['Unavailable'] : total_res = avl_res;

    outputList.push({ code: single, total_res: total_res, avl_res: avl_res });
}

console.log(outputList);
```

Just wondering if this is efficient enough or there's a better/elegant way, maybe by using other JS functions (e.g. reduce, map, etc.). Cheers!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this questions belongs on [Codereview.se].

Comment: Noted @adiga. I'll post this kind of question in the proper section next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care code performance (efficiency) that much, You would like this...

```js
const arr = [
    { "avl_res": 1, "res_status": "Available", "code": "AAA" },
    { "avl_res": 2, "res_status": "Unavailable", "code": "AAA" },
    { "avl_res": 2, "res_status": "Available", "code": "BBB" },
    { "avl_res": 1, "res_status": "Available", "code": "CCC" },
    { "avl_res": 5, "res_status": "Unavailable", "code": "CCC" },
    { "avl_res": 3, "res_status": "Unavailable", "code": "DDD" },
];

const results = [];
const findItem = {};

for (const { avl_res, code, res_status } of arr) {
    let item = findItem[code];
    const res = res_status == 'Available' ? avl_res : 0;
    if (item) {
        item.total_res += avl_res;
        item.avl_res += res;
    }
    else {
        item = { avl_res: res, total_res: avl_res, code };
        results.push(item);
        findItem[code] = item;
    }
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Why not use a plain `find` object instead of adding that as a property to array?

Comment: There is no problem to use find() But In this case, I just want to write super efficiency code, Even we should trust efficiency about build in function in JavaScript, Although find() is not just loop, it use function as loop, and function call is expensive...

Comment: I didn't mean  `array.find` method. I meant why not use a `const find = {}` object directly instead of adding that property to the array like `results.find` . Arrays shouldn't be assigned anything other than an integer property

Comment: Although in my case, Its fine to do, But for your (@adiga) sake, I edited my answer...